# Select Value of List of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#

How can i select the value from the List of keyvaluepair based on checking the key value

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, List<Properties>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, List<Properties>>();
```

Here I want to get the

```
list myList[2].Value when myLisy[2].Key=5.
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you need a `List<KeyValuePair<int, ...>>` instead of just a `Dictionary<int, ...>>`?

Comment: Key contains duplicate values also. So that here used keyvaluepair instead of Dictionary

Comment: Great! Would be good if you marked the answer that helped you as "accepted".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you need to use the List anyway I'd use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) for this query:

```
var matches = from val in myList where val.Key == 5 select val.Value;
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    foreach (Property prop in match)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

You may want to check the *match* for null.

Comment: If you're looking one specific KeyValuePair based on a key you can do something like this:


`var kvpValue =  (from kvp in kvpList where kvp.Key == key select kvp.Value).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 16):

If you're stuck with the List, you can use

```
myList.First(kvp => kvp.Key == 5).Value
```

Or if you want to use a dictionary (which might suit your needs better than the list as stated in the other answers) you can convert your list to a dictionary easily:

```
var dictionary = myList.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key);
var value = dictionary[5].Value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `Dictionary<int, List<Properties>>`. Then you can do

```
List<Properties> list = dict[5];
```

As in:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Properties>> dict = new Dictionary<int, List<Properties>>();
dict[0] = ...;
dict[1] = ...;
dict[5] = ...;

List<Properties> item5 = dict[5]; // This works if dict contains a key 5.
List<Properties> item6 = null;

// You might want to check whether the key is actually in the dictionary. Otherwise
// you might get an exception
if (dict.ContainsKey(6))
    item6 = dict[6];
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but you have to be sure that you do not have duplicate keys (`int` values) in your collection. You can store duplicate keys in a list, but not in a dictionary.

Comment: Yes. This is also what I understand the OP wants: *Here I want to get the list myList[2].Value when myLisy[2].Key=5*. If more than one key had the value of 5, which one would he take?

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**

The generic Dictionary class, introduced in .NET 2.0, uses KeyValuePair.

ITs better you make use of

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

and use `ContainsKey Method` to check the the key is there or not ..

**Example :**

```
ICollection<KeyValuePair<String, String>> openWith =
            new Dictionary<String, String>();
openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("txt", "notepad.exe"));
openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("bmp", "paint.exe"));
openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("dib", "paint.exe"));
openWith.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("rtf", "wordpad.exe"));

if (!openWith.ContainsKey("txt"))
{
       Console.WriteLine("Contains Given key");
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To get value

```
string value = "";
if (openWith.TryGetValue("tif", out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("For key = \"tif\", value = {0}.", value);
    //in you case 
   //var list= dict.Values.ToList<Property>(); 
}
```

in your caseu it will be

```
var list= dict.Values.ToList<Property>();
```

Comment: Thanks. From this we can check the key of keyvaluepair. But List<KeyValuePair<int, List<Properties>> contains List of Properties. How can i get that properties based on Index and also key of keyvalue pair. Ho do check both conditions?